# How to inherit svg's css properties using vue svg loader

Tags: vue.js, svg, loader

I am using vue-svg-loader to use my svg files as a component in Vue project. When I am rendering those svgs I am losing default css properties that are inside of the svg file. I can add those css properties inside of my component where I am rendering svg files, but that kind of violates the idea of reusable components since each svg file has its own property. Is there a way to inherit their css?

'''

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 612 792" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 792;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st1{fill:none;}
    .st2{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:10;}
    .st3{font-family:'ArialMT';}
    .st4{font-size:32px;}
</style>
<font horiz-adv-x="2048">
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely what is happening is that all of your SVG files use the same class names (`st0`, `st1`, etc).  They are overriding each other.  You'll need to:

1. manually rename the classes in each file, so they use different names, or
2. That file looks like it came from Illustrator.  Assuming they all did, then load the SVGs back into Illustrator, and re-export them.  This time change which method AI uses to set the element styles.  I don't have AI handy right now, but there will probably be three options (I don't recall exactly what they are called):

   - **Internal CSS** - what the file above is using
   - **Style attributes** - uses the `style="..."` attrinbute
   - **Attributes** - uses attributes like `fill="#ff0000"`

If you need to style the SVGs with CSS in your page, you'll probably want to use the last option. That's because `style` attributes have a higher priority than CSS, so you would need to use the CSS `!important` flag, which is not generally recommended.

[image]

Comment: Now when I render this SVG for some reason it doesn't display the IDs of the path. Does inline style hide them?

Comment: Do you mean the generated SVG file doesn't contain `id` attributes (that have been converted from layer names)?

Comment: No, So the ID are there inside of the SVG file but when I render it in the browser the IDs are not displayed

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "displayed". `id` attributes are not displayed on screen.  Perhaps it might be better to ask a new question for this. Include a sample SVG and describe what you are expecting to see. Perhaps with a mockup screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the `vue-svg-loader` documentation is pretty thin, mainly because all its configuration is done via the [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) library. There are some clues in [this FAQ](https://vue-svg-loader.js.org/faq.html#how-to-use-both-inline-and-external-svgs), which shows you how to customise the svgo configuration in your webpack config.

So maybe you want something like this in your `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');

    svgRule.uses.clear();

    svgRule
      .use('babel-loader')
      .loader('babel-loader')
      .end()
      .use('vue-svg-loader')
      .loader('vue-svg-loader')
      .options({
        svgo: {
          plugins: [
            addClassesToSVGElement: {
              classNames: ["foo", "bar"],
            }
          ],
        },
      });
  },
};
```